# iteration to check if a value is between two consecutive column values of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>df
 level       amount
 lev.0       2000
 lev.1       2300
 lev.2       2500
 lev.3       2800
 lev.4       3000
 lev.5       3450
 lev.6       3600
 lev.7       3880
 lev.8       4000
```

I want to select the lower level for which the value `2600` is in between two consecutive values of `amount` column. The output should be `lev.2`, since for 2600 the condition is satisfied when the range is `[2500, 2800]`.

I tried to develop a for cycle and a nested if statement but it does not work properly. `lev` object is empty:

```
lev = list()
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if 2600 < df["amount"][i] and 2600 >= df["amount"][i+1]:
        lev = df["level"][i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong, imagine it with `i=2`, you didn't ordered them well

```
if 2600 < 2500 and 2600 >= 2800:
if False and False:
```

The valid way would be the following, with `df["level"][i]` as result

```
lev = None
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if df["amount"][i] < 2600 <= df["amount"][i+1]:
        lev = df["level"][i]
```

---

But with `pandas`, there's always a nice trick :

```
lev = df.loc[(df['amount'] < 2600) & (2600 <= df.shift(-1)['amount']), 'level'].values[0]
```

- `df['amount'] < 2600` to get the lower bound
- `2600 <= df.shift(-1)['amount']` to get the upper bound